# Print name and id of radio button?

Tags: c#, html, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have created a radio button list and when I select the radio button and click submit button I am printing the id of selected option and i want to print both name and id of selected radio button.

I did everything I knew but I got errors I don't know how to do this.

This is my model.

```
public class Company
{
    public Nullable<int>  SelectedValue { get; set; }   
   
    public List<Department> Departments
    {
        get
        {
            SampleContext context = new SampleContext();
            return context.Departments.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a method(given below) but it didn't work

```
public string depName
{
    get
    {
        Department department = new Department();
        Company c = new Company();
        var dpname = department.Department_Name.Where(department.Department_Id == c.SelectedValue);
        return dpname;
    }
}
```

This is my controller code

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("RadioDep")]
public string RadioDepartment(Company company)
{
    
    if (company.SelectedValue is null)
    {
        return "you did not select any department";
    }
    else
    {
        return "you selected"(i want my department name here) " department with id "+company.SelectedValue;
    }
}
```

This is view code

```
@model Testing_Helpers.Models.Company  
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RadioDep";
}
<div style="font-family:Arial">
    <h2>RadioDep</h2>
    @using (@Html.BeginForm())
    {
        foreach(var department in Model.Departments)
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedValue, department.Department_Id, 
            (department.IsSelected.HasValue && department.IsSelected.Value)? new {@checked = "checked"}:null)
            @department.Department_Name
            <br/>
        }

        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe adding FirstOrDefault will fix it. I am no expert but since you have a list of departments it might work.
Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ActionName("RadioDep")]
    public string RadioDepartment(Company company)
    {

            
            
            
        if (company.SelectedValue is null)
        {
            return "you did not select any department";
        }
        else
        { 
            //EDIT 1 : 
            var dpname = company.Departments.Where(x=>x.Department_Id == company.SelectedValue).FirstOrDefault().Department_Name;
            return "you selected"+dpname+" department with id "+company.SelectedValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am getting error in var dpname = department.Where(x=>x.Department_Id == company.SelectedValue).FirstOrDefault().Department_Name; i made some modification bcoz i was getting error var dpname = d.Department_Name.Where(Department_Id == company.SelectedValue).FirstOrDefault().Department_Name;  and now i am getting error at d.Department_Id == company.SelectedValue stating cannot convert bool to system.func

Comment: i edit the solution can you try like this? var dpname = company.Departments.Where(x=>x.Department_Id == company.SelectedValue).FirstOrDefault().Department_Name;